# Provide a model for which the following is true $\forall x\forall y\forall z((S(x,y)\land S(y,z)) \implies S(x,z))$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

> My question relates to the idea of **satisfiability**. If one can provide a model for which the following formula is **true** does it mean it is **satisfiable**?

$$\forall x\forall y\forall z\,((S(x,y) \land S(y,z))\implies S(x,z)). $$

Is the above formula **satisfiable** if I have the following model:

$A = \{a,b,c\}$

$S = \{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\}$?

If it is **satisfiable**, what would be required to make this formula **valid** in this model?

If it is not **satisfiable** what would be an appropriate model to make it **satisfiable**?

Comment: Was the last $y$ meant to be $z$?

Comment: yes. corrected it. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several terminological issues in your question, so (at the risk of appearing too pedantic) let me try to address those.

Given a sentence $\varphi$ and a structure $M$, we can talk about the sentence being **true** or **false** in $M$. To talk about **true** or **false**, we need both a sentence and a structure.

So the phrases "$\varphi$ is true" and "$\varphi$ is false" make no sense unless we implicitly have a structure $M$ around that we're interested in.

On the other hand, a sentence $\varphi$ is **satisfiable** if it is true in *some* structure. And $\varphi$ is **valid** if it is true in *every* structure. To talk about **satisfiable** or **valid**, we only need a sentence, we don't need a structure.

So the phrases "$\varphi$ is satisfiable in $M$" and "$\varphi$ is valid in $M$" make no sense. On its own, $\varphi$ is either satisfiable or not and either valid or not.

Now to answer your questions one by one, with the above in mind:

> If one can provide a model for which the following formula is true does it mean it is satisfiable?

Yes, this is the definition of satisfiable. To prove that $\varphi$ is satisfiable, you can exhibit a structure $M$ in which $\varphi$ is true.

> Is the above formula satisfiable if I have the following model? \begin{align*} A &= \{a,b,c\}\\ S&= \{(a,b), (b,c), (a,c)\}\end{align*}

Yes, exhibiting the structure $M = (A,S)$ proves that $\varphi$ is satisfiable, since $\varphi$ is true in $M$.

> If it is satisfiable, what would be required to make this formula valid in this model?

This question is not well-formed ("valid in this model" makes no sense). In fact, the sentence is not valid, and you can prove this by exhibiting a structure in which the sentence is false. For example: \begin{align*} A &= \{a,b,c\}\\ S&= \{(a,b), (b,c)\}\end{align*}

> If it is not satisfiable what would be an appropriate model to make it satisfiable?

A model doesn't *make* a sentence satisfiable. It's either satisfiable or it's not. You can *prove* that a sentence is satisfiable by exhibiting a model, like you did above.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and reasoned response (the pedanticism was necessary). Your students are lucky. I think I got it now. I have a couple of questions by extension that I am not sure how to put into words. I will make use of the example we have been using to assist me in explaining what I am unsure of. If I change $S$ to also include the tuple $(a,a)$ so that $S = {(a,a),(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)}$ can I "substitute" the first predicate symbol in the formula with $S(a,a)$ in that $\forall x\forall y\forall z\,((S(a,a) \land S(y,z))\implies S(x,z))$ so that $x=a$ and $y=a$ or do $\forall$x and..

Comment: $\forall$y have to refer to different concrete elements in $A$?

Comment: The formula you wrote has a completely different meaning. It says "for all $x$, $y$, and $z$, if $S(a,a)$ holds and $S(y,z)$ holds, then $S(x,z)$ holds". This is *false* in your model, since taking $x = c$, $y = a$, $z = b$, we have $S(a,a)$ and $S(a,b)$ but not $S(c,b)$.

Comment: The problem here is that you can't just substitute elements for some variables in the middle of a formula and preserve truth. Instead, the way to do this is governed by the quantifiers. The sentence starts $\forall x$, so we can pick some value to substitute for $x$, and the resulting formula will still be true in the model. Taking $x = a$ gives $\forall y\forall z\, ((S(a,y)\land S(y,z)\rightarrow S(a,z))$. Now this formula again starts $\forall y$, so we can pick some element to substitute for $y$. Taking $y = a$ gives $\forall z\, ((S(a,a)\land S(a,z)\rightarrow S(a,z))$.

Comment: Note that this formula *is* true in the model. And no, we are not required to interpret distinct quantified variables as distinct elements of $A$.

Comment: I did not word my question clearly. Your last comment answers my question directly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it suffices to find a model that satisfies the formula.

Consider $A=\{a\}, S=\{(a,a)\}$.